# How to create REST/SOAP wcf web service from asp.net mvc2 project and consume in android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, soap

I have a MVC2 ASP.Net project. I want to make a web service which internally calls the controller's action (since logic are coded in controller's action). And finally I will consume the web service from android sdk. The web servc

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a JSON result from MVC instead of the default action result, and then anything (including Android devices) doing a GET or POST to the endpoint (controller action in MVC) depending on how you code it can consume it.

I wouldn't bother doing a WCF service for this endpoint unless you need some other functionality there (admittedly some of my read-only WCF endpoints are exposed using SOAP, XML, and JSON just by expanding the configuration).

Comment: Yes; you are right. May be I don't need WCF since I don't need other functionality. But some of my action returns ActionResult. By the way, how do I consume that action?

Comment: You create a JsonResult instead of an action result, then you can use jQuery or other AJAX/web framework to perform the get or post.  There are definitely other examples out there on this.